# Is there any evidence that people follow crowds less at a certain age?

Tags: developmental-psychology

A while back I saw a chart of psychological development milestones, and it said around the age of 28 people tend to think less in a collective and more on their own. I can't find the chart nor can I find anything backing up that claim since. Is there any evidence that this is true?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. As a possible counterargument, I wonder how trade unions survive without collective thinking and agreement.

Comment: Well, older people definitely don't lose all sense of collectivism. But just from observation it seems like those who are 24+ tend to think more for themselves rather than follow a group, especially compared to those who are college-aged and younger. I wasn't sure if that is cultural or psychological.